# UWP for IoT custom Listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, uwp-xaml, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

Has been 2 days I'm struggling with a Listbox; I'm working on an interface for raspberry Pi 3 (*With windows 10 IoT*). This list is meant to contain a list of projects obtained from a web service ... Once one of this is clicked i should redirect the user to a new frame containing tasks for that project ... I was thinking of doing so using the ID of the project using a listbox (*the user will have just 3 buttons and no mouse or keyboard*) ... The main problem is i can't find a way to hide (*as i was used to do in normal vb.net forms*) the id in the list ...

in vb.net i used to create a listbox with

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(New ListItem("id", "string"))
```

With xaml it seems it's not possible to do so... how can i do so ? should i use some other component instead of listbox ?

thanks in advance!!!

UPDATE:

My listbox is just an empty one:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="listaprova">
</ListBox>
```

i've been trying with this code with no results:

```
listaprova.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem() with {Tag = "id", Content = "test"})
Dim test As reader.ProjList() = Await list.ObtainProjectsAsync("Admin", "admin") 
listaprova.Items.Add(test(0).ID, test(0).Nome)
```

another attempt i made was creating a new listboxItem and add it sequentially:

```
Dim lp As New ListBoxItem()
lp.Tag = "id"
lp.Content = "test"
listaprova.Items.Add(lp)
listaprova.Items.Add(lp)
```

but at the second add the app crash.

Comment: please share you xaml and some code

Comment: What do you mean by 'hide the Id in the list'? With line `listaprova.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem() with {Tag = "id", Content = "test"})` you shouldn't see the id. Are you suing any *ItemTempaltes*, any class for your items?

Comment: In xaml, you can create the listbox with `<ListBox Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="listaprova">
            <ListBoxItem Tag="id" Content="test" IsTapEnabled="True" Tapped="ListBoxItem_Tapped" />
            <ListBoxItem Tag="id" Content="test"/>
        </ListBox>`